# Predict future gas price

Tags: web3js, gas, ethers.js, gas-estimate

I am wondering, is there a way to "predict" future gas prices? I would like to find a gas price or at least approximation of it for the future block, so the one that is currently pending.

Comment: Can you clarify how far in the future you need to predict? Also what level of accuracy you require?

Comment: You could try using forecasting models.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to predict the gas price for long-term future. You may be able to "predict" the gas usage in units of gas, but not the actual price, because the price is determined by the network supply and demand at the time of the transaction creation. In other words, the gas price is determined by factors outside your control. You can predict it for the next few days based on the current network usage, but not for longer period.

Answer (score 0):

For Ethereum, you can find all the relevant information in [this documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/).

This is the equation of gas fee:

```
units of gas used * (base fee + priority fee)
```

- Units of gas depending on the complexity of your transaction, which is a fixed number.
- The priority fee is the "Tip" you give to the validator, which is not deterministic. But you can somehow use the current priority fee as a benchmark.
- The base fee is calculated based on an equation related to the previous block size.

The maximum gas a block can hold is 30M. If Block A contains 30M gas, which means the network reaches the maximum capacity, the base fee of Block A+1 will be increased by 12.5%.

In the case of Block A contains 15M gas, which means the network is somehow balanced. There will be no change in the base fee for the subsequent block.

If Block contains less than 15M gas, the base fee will decrease.

Some RPC methods that may help you:

[eth_estimategas](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_estimategas) to estimate a transaction's total gas fee.

[eth_gasprice](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_gasprice) to get the current base fee.

[eth_getBlockByNumber](https://docs.chainstack.com/api/ethereum/eth_getblockbynumber) to get the current block's gas usage and limit.

Hope this helps.